# Aprender sobre columns - css

Tags: front-end, layout, css

Certo dia, tive que desenvolver um site onde o layout tinha algumas imagens que não ficavam exatamente lado a lado, e como não sabia sobre o columns, acabei alinhando tudo no absolute e aquela bagunça no responsivo.

Alguém poderia explicar de forma simples e passo a passo sobre como usar o columns?

Pelo que vi, parece com ele vc consegue atacar a div/imagem que quiser e definir margin, altura etc...

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil trabalhar o responsivo usando 'display:inline' e 'display:block' nas medias queries.

Answer (score -1):

Grande vou te passar um link que me ajuda muito sobre propriedades do CSS até hoje que pode te ajudar nessa parte de alinhamento, [Segue Link](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/), recomendo você aprender um pouco sobre FlexBox que faz exatamente o que deseja, é novo mais muitos desenvolvedores vão começar a usar, [FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, vou ler mais sobre...

Comment: Estava lendo um pouco, mas foca ele foca mais no flexbox. Tava querendo saber mais mesmo sobre o columns, mas obrigado de qualquer forma.